# PHP mysql fixed connection to utf8, but now existing greek data is useless

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I have a mysql database storing some fields in greek characters.  In my html I have charset=utf-8 and my database columns are defined with encoding utf_general_ci. But I was not setting the connection encoding so far. As a result I have a database that doesn't display the greek characters well, but when reading back in PHP, it all shows well.

Now I try to do this the right way, so I added also in my database functions.

```
     $mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

This works great for new entries.

But for existing entries, the problem is that when I read data in PHP, it comes garbled, since now the connection encoding has changed.

Is there a way to fix my data and make them useful again? I can continue working my old way, but I know it's wrong and can cause me more problems in the future.

Comment: you should write an script to update them.(-:

Comment: how can i update the endodings, if they are invalid?

Comment: Your encodings are not invalid as they were working before, but they are mislabelled. What encoding does the database use now? What encoding did it use before? What are the old entries actually encoded with?

Comment: @NielsB. now its utf-8 like before. but because i didn't set in the connection as utf-8, it is not readable in the mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue as follows:

1. in a PHP script, retrieve the information as I do now, i.e without setting the connection. This way the mistake will be inverted and corrected and in your php file you will have the characters in the correct utf-8 format.
2. in the same PHP script, write back the information with setting the connection to utf-8
   at this point the correct characters are in the database
3. I changed all my read/write functions of your site to use the utf-8 from now on